# replace href text in HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace, href

Is it possible to use `Javascript` to change the a `href` value in the following code from `href="http://**store**.mystitexxx.co.nz"` to `href="http://**www**.mystitexxx.co.nz"`?  It needs to be specific to this DIV or image, ie not global

```
<div id="ctl00" class="hidden-xs">
   <h1 class="logo clearfix">
      <a href="http://store.mystorexxx.co.nz" title="My Store"><img class="img-responsive"src="/user/files/logo.png?t=1601271313" title="My Store" alt="My Store"/></a>
   </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I suspect you're not asking the full question here.  Do you want it to ALWAYS replace with EXACTLY that url? Or do you want it to "detect" if there's a `www` in the url already, and if not, add the `www`?

Comment: I always want to replace it with that exact url, but just fir the logo image, not elsewhere on the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gee, it seems like all the other answers are pretty complicated.

It's simple:

```
jQuery('h1.logo a').attr('href', 'http://www.mystitexxx.co.nz');
```

Or, if you don't know where to put this / how to include it, then:

Between your `<head>` and `</head>` tags, add this:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('h1.logo a').attr('href', 'http://www.mystitexxx.co.nz');
    }); 
</script>
```

And, if you don't already have jQuery loading, then just add it in like so (again, between `<head>` tags):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('h1.logo a').attr('href', 'http://www.mystitexxx.co.nz');
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you need it to be specific to this exact link, just:

```js
document.getElementById("link").href = "http://www.mystitexxx.co.nz";
```

```html
<div id="ctl00" class="hidden-xs">
   <h1 class="logo clearfix">
      <a href="http://store.mystorexxx.co.nz" title="My Store" id="link"><img class="img-responsive"src="/user/files/logo.png?t=1601271313" title="My Store" alt="My Store"/></a>
   </h1>
</div>
```

With jQuery:

```
$("#link").attr("href", "http://www.mystitexxx.co.nz");
```

**Edit:** If you don't have control over the HTML to add an ID. (If you did, why would you want to change the href with Javascript? :P)

```js
document.querySelector("h1.logo a").href = "http://www.mystorexxx.co.nz";
//$("h1.logo a").attr("href", "http://www.mystitexxx.co.nz");
```

```html
<div id="ctl00" class="hidden-xs">
   <h1 class="logo clearfix">
      <a href="http://store.mystorexxx.co.nz" title="My Store"><img class="img-responsive"src="/user/files/logo.png?t=1601271313" title="My Store" alt="My Store"/></a>
   </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: THank you, but unfortunately the img does not have an ID and I can't directly add one, is there a way to add it first using Javascript?

Comment: I thought it was you code, Ill edit it without using ID.

Comment: One thing to consider is will the HTML your working with match EXACTLY to what you have shown us as an example. If you have additional anchor points then the code will have to be modified to handle them. Some how the link you want to replace has to be uniquely identifiable either by an ID or by its place in the mark up. If you need multiple links change then the code will be entirely different.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .selected{
        background-color : green;
    }
    </style>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.logo a img.img-responsive').attr('src', "http://www.mystitexxx.co.nz")

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="ctl00" class="hidden-xs">
   <h1 class="logo clearfix">
      <a href="http://store.mystorexxx.co.nz" title="My Store"><img class="img-responsive"src="/user/files/logo.png?t=1601271313" title="My Store" alt="My Store"/></a>
   </h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```